# Test-Focused EvaluatorTrace Monad?

Tags: plutus, plutus-playground, monad

Is there infrastructure for writing unit/integration tests for our contracts, without running the full playground?  Is there a test-focused EvaluatorTrace monad, for example?

Answer (score 2):

There are now test capabilities in the Plutus.Contract.Test module which uses the Tasty library.

This is explained more fully in [the unit tests section of lecture 8 of iteration 1 of the Plutus Pioneer Program](https://plutus-pioneer-program.readthedocs.io/en/latest/week8.html#unit-testing).

Some highlights:

```
checkPredicate :: String -> TracePredicate -> EmulatorTrace () -> TestTree
```

There are a number of functions for producing a TracePredicate. For example:

```
-- | Check that the funds in the wallet have changed by the given amount, exluding fees.
walletFundsChange :: Wallet -> Value -> TracePredicate
```

Which can then be combined into a test function:

```
tests :: TestTree
tests = checkPredicateOptions
   (defaultCheckOptions & emulatorConfig .~ emCfg)
"token sale trace"
   ( walletFundsChange (Wallet 1) (Ada.lovelaceValueOf   10_000_000  <> assetClassValue token (-60))
.&&. walletFundsChange (Wallet 2) (Ada.lovelaceValueOf (-20_000_000) <> assetClassValue token   20)
.&&. walletFundsChange (Wallet 3) (Ada.lovelaceValueOf (- 5_000_000) <> assetClassValue token    5)
   )
myTrace
```

Which can then be run like this:

```
Prelude Spec.Trace> import Test.Tasty
Prelude Test.Tasty Spec.Trace> defaultMain tests
token sale trace: OK (1.22s)

All 1 tests passed (1.22s)
```

Naturally, these tests can be configured to run as part of "cabal test".

Answer (score 0):

You can use Plutus Playground to test your code and maybe in the near future we will have more options.